# Windows Server 2019 Windows Backup Issue with Hyper-V

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2019, windows-server-backup

I am running Windows Server 2019 and have configured Windows Server Backup.

The backup is to a dedicated backup disk and consists of the following options:

- Bare Metal Recovery
- C:
- System Reserved
- System state
- Hyper-V (several VMs selected)

The Hyper-V backups routinely fail with the following error:

```
Error in backup of C:\VHDs\Alderaan\Virtual Machines\A118C476-9DB8-499E-AE63-85B2F8DE0563.VMRS during enumerate: Error [0x80070020] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Application backup
Writer Id: {66841CD4-6DED-4F4B-8F17-FD23F8DDC3DE}
   Component: A118C476-9DB8-499E-AE63-85B2F8DE0563
   Caption     : Online\alderaan
   Logical Path: 
   Error           : 8078010D
   Error Message   : Enumeration of the files failed.

   Detailed Error  : 80070020
   Detailed Error Message : (null)
```

The error example above is for one VM, but all of them fail with the same error. At the time of backup, all the VMs are running.

The other Windows backup options complete without issue (as seen below).

```
Backup of volume C: succeeded.

Backup of volume \\?\Volume{08035f94-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\ succeeded.

Application backup
Writer Id: {66841CD4-6DED-4F4B-8F17-FD23F8DDC3DE}
   Component: Host Component
   Caption     : Host Component
   Logical Path:
```

I have tried to do just a one-time backup of only the Hyper-V component VMs and have received the same error as identified above.

Comment: Have you considered using Veeam Agent and B&R to backup physical host and Hyper-v VM? They are industry-standard tools for the job.

Comment: @A.Newgate I just checked out the Veeam Community Edition and it works great. I was concerned about cost for my lab setup, but at the price of Community (free) you really can't beat it. Does everything I need it to do.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

Can it be that it does copy the drives twice? The VM folders should not be backed up as part of C: (i.e. file backup) but ONLY as part of the VM backups. If you backup C as DRIVE - well, the path where it faily is there.

Comment: I have tried just backing up the Hyper-V component VMs and I get the same error.

Comment: just a suggestion but ehy not using veeam?

Comment: For a small isolated setup - there should not be a NEED to have another software. In fact, unless confirmed as a bug, I would say the error indicates something wrong with the setup, and I at least would be VERY reluctant to avoid the symptoms without treating the problem.

Comment: @djdomi this is a lab setup; trying to stick with out of the box tools.

Comment: Well, then you did not heared in the past about the windows server backup bug? i dont trust in that anymore. Moreover, Veeam is free to use

Comment: Nope actually not heard of it in 2019.

Comment: @djdomi I actually gave up trying to make this work and tried out the Community Edition of Veeam. It's a great piece of software and works without a hitch. It is a crime in my opinion that Windows Backup in its current state ships with the OS .

Comment: Not arguing here - even IF it works.... it does do one thing, that is put in some basic functionality for others to use, but generally it is not exactly a stellar piece of advanced software. It should do a basic job, though.

Comment: Tom i agree to you but sometimes third parties do or give a better choice...